# Learning Java: Celcius to Fahrenheit Conversion

Tags: java, beginner

This is a short Celcius to Fahrenheit conversion calculator that calculates the average of all entries before exiting. This program performs exactly to the required specification.

I have some concern about the cleanliness of the multiple variable declaration and initialization to zero in a single line. I've seen this done on a few sites, and it works, but is it conventional to see Java variables initialized in this way?

Regarding assigning everything zero, is it more or less appropriate to give a variable a value when declaring it?

I'm also concerned with the `double conversion` variable in the `if` statement, is this is scoped properly, or should `conversion` be declared with the other variables?

These were just a few of points I noticed myself, please review for syntax, convention, and readability.

```
package temperature;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature {

public static void main(String[] args) {       
    int counter = 0;
    double input = 0;
    double celciusInputs, fahrenheitInputs = celciusInputs = 0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
      System.out.print("Enter Temp in Centigrade or <= -100.0 to quit: ");
      input = in.nextDouble();
      if (input > -100.0) {
        double conversion = ((9.0/5.0) * input) + 32.0;
        System.out.printf("Temperature: F(%.1f) C(%.1f)\n", conversion, input);
        celciusInputs += input;
        fahrenheitInputs += conversion;
        counter += 1;
      }
    } while (input > -100.0); 
    
    // Calculate averages
    celciusInputs /= counter;
    fahrenheitInputs /= counter;
    
    System.out.printf("Average: Centigrade (%.1f) Average: Fahrenheit(%.1f)",
            celciusInputs, fahrenheitInputs);
    
    in.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: The assignment of zero in the declaration of auto variables is unnecessary. This was one of the explicit things Java changed from C because it was a source of many bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `double celciusInputs, fahrenheitInputs = celciusInputs = 0;`

Variables declared and initialized this way are hard to read. Prefer:

```
double celciusInputs = 0;
double fahrenheitInputs = 0;
```

---

> `double celciusInputs, fahrenheitInputs = celciusInputs = 0;`

The `Inputs` in the name signals to me that it is an array of values. It is not. Prefer `celciusInputsSum` and `fahrenheitInputsSum`

---

> `System.out.print("Enter Temp in Centigrade or <= -100.0 to quit: ");`

Spell out `Temp` as `temperature` to avoid confusion. Centigrade should also be worded as "Celsius" to avoid confusion (even variable names use "celsius", not "centigrade")

Why is minimum allowed temperature -100.0 °C? Absolute zero is at -273.15 °C

---

> `input = in.nextDouble();`

Error handling should be added. What do you want to do when user enters `foobar` as input?

---

> `double conversion = ((9.0/5.0) * input) + 32.0;`

From this line alone, we do not know the units. Prefer `fahrenheitConverted` or similar

---

> `counter += 1;`

Instead of summing the inputs, perhaps consider `ArrayList` to store the inputs. The sum can only go so far before `celciusInputs` and `fahrenheitInputs` overflow. It also provides more flexibility if you want to do other calculations (such as calculating mode and median, along with the mean/average)

---

> ```
> celciusInputs /= counter;
> fahrenheitInputs /= counter;
> ```

Doing it like this means the variable names no longer reflect its contents. Prefer using new variables like this: `double celsiusInputAverage = celciusInputs / numInputs`

---

> `public static void main(String[] args) {`

This line is missing indentation (2 spaces)

Answer (score 2):

fromthestackandback has made some good points.
Here's my take

1. Declare and initialize each variable on its own line.
2. Use meaningful names - `celciusSum` means so much more than `celciusInputs`
3. Separate different parts of your processing - getting input (which you should validate), converting data and reporting results are worth splitting out
4. Don't change the meaning of your data - at one point in your code `celciusInputs` is a total, then it magically becomes an average
5. Use try with resource in preference to explicitly closing things
6. Avoid repeated tests - your code tests against the exit value twice, I'd rather not

My rewrite below tries to address these issues while remaining close to your original in style.

```
package temperature;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter = 0;
    double celciusValue = 0;
    double celciusSum = 0;
    double fahrenheitSum = 0;

    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {

      while (true) {
        celciusValue = getCelcius(in);
        if (celciusValue > -100.0) {
          double fahrenheitValue = celciusToFahrenheit(celciusValue);
          reportResultOfConversion(celciusValue, fahrenheitValue);
          celciusSum += celciusValue;
          fahrenheitSum += fahrenheitValue;
          counter += 1;
        }
        else {
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    // Report averages

    reportAverages(counter, celciusSum, fahrenheitSum);

  }

  private static void reportAverages(int counter, double celciusSum, double fahrenheitSum) {
    System.out.printf("Average: Centigrade (%.1f) Average: Fahrenheit(%.1f)",
        celciusSum / counter, fahrenheitSum / counter);
  }

  private static void reportResultOfConversion(double celciusValue, double fahrenheitValue) {
    System.out.printf("Temperature: F(%.1f) C(%.1f)\n", fahrenheitValue, celciusValue);
  }

  private static double celciusToFahrenheit(double celciusValue) {
    double fahrenheitValue = ((9.0 / 5.0) * celciusValue) + 32.0;
    return fahrenheitValue;
  }

  private static double getCelcius(Scanner in) {
    double input;
    while (true) {
      try {
        System.out.print("Enter Temperature in Celcius or <= -100.0 to quit: ");
        input = in.nextDouble();
        return input;
      }
      catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.err.println("That value was not valid, please try again");
        in.next(); // skip the bad token
      }
    }
  }
}
```